# Any foolproof merger of text files (fixed text with LF)

Tags: text, merge, linefeed

```
bash$ cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt > ./mergedfile.txt
```

If any of the `file*.txt` does not have proper LF/EOF termination, I will get lesser line count.

Are there any failsafe approaches to fixed the LF/EOF issue?

Avoiding to the following results (assuming text with 2-liner in running numbers 1 2 in each line, and one of them had a malformed LF termination).

```
1
2
1
21
2
```

Answer (score 0):

I am answering my own question and hope to get better alternatives.

instead of:

```
cat file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt > ./mergedfile.txt
```

I was told it would be better with the following:

```
awk 1 file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt > ./mergedfile.txt
```